# Solving a linked recurrent relations

Tags: convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations

I am trying to solving a linked recurrent relations.

$$
\left\{\begin{matrix}
T_t &= &(a_{t}p_{n}+c_{t}+b_{t}p_r+d_{t})*(1-P_o)\\
a_{t+1} &= &T_t*f(T_t)+(1-p_n)*a_t\\
b_{t+1} &= &T_t*(1-f(T_t))+(1-p_r)*b_t\\
c_{t+1} &= &(a_tp_n+c_t)Po\\
d_{t+1} &= &(b_tp_r+d_t)Po\\
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
where $f(T_t)$ is kind of probability function which is not linear function. $p_n$, $p_r$ and $P_o$ are less than 1 and larger than 0.

The initial values are 
$$
\left\{\begin{matrix}
a_{1} &= & 100\\
b_{1} &= & 0\\
c_{1} &= & 0\\
d_{1} &= & 0\\
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
Since $f(T_t)$ is in $a_t$ and $b_t$, I thought it can not be solved as matrix form.

How can I determine whether the linked recurrent relations converge or not?
Is there an idea to solve the convergence value?

I put the initial values to the linked recurrent relations in MATLAB, and find out the relations converge.

Comment: just checking  so we have two indices, $n$ and $t$ for variable $a,b,c,d$?

Comment: There were typo, so I corrected it. Thank you